# iis reverse proxy (arr + url rewrite) return 404 on some urls

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, wso2, reverse-proxy, arr

We have ASP.Net MVC app and wso2 server as OAuth server. We need to access both over one IP. We haven't ability to use hostnames :(

So I configure web.config like this:

```
<rules>
            <rule name="wso2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^wso2/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://some-server:9443/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Rewrite Location Header" preCondition="IsRedirection" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="^http://[^/]+/(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="https://some-server:8888/wso2/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding" enabled="true">
                <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="outbound rewrite" preCondition="wso2" enabled="true">
                <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/oauth2(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="/wso2/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
              <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
              </preCondition>
                <preCondition name="wso2">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/wso2/(.*)" />
                </preCondition>
                <preCondition name="IsRedirection">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3\d\d" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>

        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

And when I try to open url: https://some-server:8888/wso2/carbon/admin/login.jsp it opening correctly, like https://some-server:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp

But when I,m trying  https://some-server:8888/wso2/carbon, which must redirect to https://some-server:8888/wso2/carbon/admin/login.jsp I get 404 error. And no logs on appache. 
IIS Failed Requests Log looks good until:

```
36. -PRECONDITION_EVALUATION Verbose
Input {RESPONSE_STATUS} 
ExpandedInput 404 
MatchType 0 
Pattern 3\d\d 
Negate false 
Succeeded false
MatchType Pattern
```

But IIS not ask appache (nothing in appache logs and wireshark)

Anyone know solution?

Comment: 1. whats the value you have put for <Hostname> in carbon.xml of the WSO2 products. 
2. When you see the 404, do you see any entries in the http_access.log of WSO2 product?
3. Have you seen any errors or reasons for 404 in browser console?

Comment: 1. some-server 2. nothing (Wireshark shows nothing too) 3.no This is IIS problem I think. 4. some-server = localhost

Comment: I seem to have a similar issue, but for me it's much simpler.

Comment: I seem to have a similar issue, but for me the configuration is much simpler. My config is done entirely in IIS with the following inbound rule: url after / matches (*.) rewrite to localhost:81/{R:1} condition {HTTP_HOST} matches ^{subdomain}\.(+.)$
multiple servers on localhost:81, 82, etc. using apache and tomcat. behavior looks similar for both configurations. static calls like login.jsp, index.php etc. all work fine, but dynamic urls like /blog/my-page or user/username/account all fail. any idea if this is related? otherwise I will make my own post.